# Sort by Name and by Category Backbone Collection

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone collection and two buttons. What i want to do is if i click on button1 it should sort the collection by Name and if button2 is clicked it should sort by category.

I tried this

```
comparator : function(model){
     return model.get("Name");
}
```

My question is can i have two comparator in my collection? how would i sort the collection by name and category separately. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could attach a sort variable to the collection and use that in the comparator:

```
    App.List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      initialize: function() {
        this.sortVar = 'Name';
      },
      comparator: function(model){
        return model.get(this.sortVar);
      }
    })
```

Then just change sortVar when the link is clicked and call sort().

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is using the **sortBy** method (it comes from underscore but it's available for Backbone.Collection) : with that method you simply pass in the model property name. Note that the sortBy method returns an array.

Here I have an independent view for the buttons. Triggering a sort event enables other views (for example, the view that handles the rendering of the list) to respond to the sort event and re-render themselves.

```
app.ButtonsView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: '#buttons',

        events: {
            'click #sortByNameBtn' : 'sortByName',
            'click #sortByCategoryBtn' : 'sortByCategory'
        },

        sortByName : function(){
            app.mycollection.models = app.mycollection.sortBy('name');  
            app.mycollection.trigger('sort');                                                       
        }, 

        sortByCategory : function(){                    
            app.mycollection.models = app.mycollection.sortBy('category');  
            app.mycollection.trigger('sort');                                                                       
        }
    });
```

Reference: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html (search for sortBy)

Using sortBy **the 'sort' event won't be fired** so that is why I trigger it myself on the collection.
Also, sortBy may not work for Date properties or others that are complex to sort, so use the comparator for that.